# How to solve problems such as: find $A(x)$, the accumulation function of $f(x)=x^2$ such that $A(x)= \frac{x^3}3$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, soft-question

Suppose that $A(x)= \int_a^x t^2 \mathrm dt $ and that $A(x)=  \frac{x^3}2$. Find $a$.

I think that the only solution is $a = 0$.

Assuming this is correct, is there a general method to find number a?

---

- In general, we are interested in determining the primitive of a function f for which constant C is null. This particular primitive seems more " basic" as others, since the others can be obtained from it adding some constant C.
- For example, all primitives of $f(x)=x^2$ will be written in terms of the "basic" primitive $F(x) = \frac{x^3}3$
- Not all area functions ("accumulation functions") of a function, say, once again $f(x)=x^2$, will be identical to its "basic" primitive. For example, the area function defined as $x \mapsto \int_5^x t^2 \mathrm dt$ is not identical to the “basic” primitive of $f$, that is, to $F(x)= \frac{x^3}3$. (See image below.)
- Apparently, only the function $x \mapsto \int_0^x t^2\mathrm dt$ is identical to the basic primitive $F(x)$ as defined above.
- Hence my question: is there a method to determine which particular area function of a function $f$ (with which domain, and in particular ***which number $a$ as limit of integration***) is identical to the "basic/standard" primitive of $f$?

---

The image below shows that  the area function *A(x)* with *a=0* is identical to the " basic" primitive of *f(x)=x²*. this is not the case with a=5.

[image]

Comment: I’ve fixed all the major formatting problems but it’s really hard to understand things. Please take a look at MathJax.

Comment: @LucasHenrique. Thanks a lot for editing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We require $A(x) = x^3/3$ and we compute
$$  A(x) = \int_a^x t^2 \,\mathrm{d}t = \left. \frac{t^3}{3} \right|_{t=a}^x = \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{a^3}{3}  \text{.}  $$
Equality of these two expressions for $A(x)$ requires $-a^3/3 = 0$, which forces $a = 0$.

The general technique, demonstrated above, is to compute the definite integral, then solve the resulting equality for the value or values of $a$ that satisfy it.

Warning: The set of accumulation functions is *not* the full set of antiderivatives and it can be confusing to think otherwise at this time.

An example of this deficiency of accumulation functions is: find $b$ such that $B(x)$, the accumulation function of $2x$ is $B(x) = x^2 + 10$.  We proceed by the generic technique:
$$  \int_b^x 2t \,\mathrm{d}t = \left. \frac{2t^2}{2} \right|_{b}^x = x^2 - b^2  \text{.}  $$
This gives the equation $10 = -b^2$, which has no solution (because the left-hand side is positive and the right-hand side is negative for all choices of $b$).  However, $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( \frac{x^2}{2}+10 \right) = 2x$, so this $B$ is an example of an antiderivative of $2x$ which is not an accumulation of $2x$.

Also, beware this notion of "basic": Any identity that happens to contain a constant offset makes "basic"ness unclear.  Which is more "basic": $\sec^2 \theta$ or $\tan^2 \theta + 1$.  The two expressions are equal for all $\theta$ and the "${}+1$" is not optional.

Comment: Thanks for this clear and detailed answer.